# android : implement FacebookMessenger-like tablayout

Tags: java, android, facebook

how to achieve this style ??

[image]

I'm not sure if it is some sort of a customized tablayout or anything. 
any idea how to implement such thing ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
    android:track="@drawable/switch_bg" />
```

Selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_pressed_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_holo_light" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

The deactivated version (xhdpi version that Android is using)  The deactivated version [image]

The pressed slider: The pressed slider  [image]

The activated slider (on state):The activated slider [image]

The default version (off state): enter image description here [image]

Library : [SwitchButton](https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton)